# batch file to make macro

Tags: batch-file, macros, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a batch file. I putted a shortcut on the batch file which is (Ctr + Alt + 1). I want this batch file to output "Hello World!" in a field selected by the mouse cursor. I don't want any external program.

Example: you have a Sticky Note and you put your cursor in it. Then you press (Ctr + Alt + 1) and "Hello World!" appears.

Comment: Batch isn't really the best option for this, as it has no way to mimic keyboard presses. Your best option would be to look into a visual basic script `.vbs` or somekind of hybrid between batch and visual basic.

Comment: The closest [tag:batch-file]-related thing that comes to my mind is using the `clip` command in a batch script; so you can at least write text to the clipboard, which can then be pasted in other applications (_Ctrl+V_)...

Answer (score 1):

```
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.SendKeys "Hello World!"  
sh.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 100
sh.SendKeys "^p"
```

Is the best you can do. Above is VBScript.